# Is this admin area protection technique in my CodeIgniter admin controller only for one ip address good?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to protect my admin section but I am not sure if something like php if ip condition in construct of my Admin controller is enough.

I have all my files out of the root so only assets like images, css , js and index is available if ddos will be successful. Which is ok.

However, is condition like this enough for protecting my admin area?

Begining of my Admin class controller:

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();

            if ($this->input->ip_address() != '127.0.0.1')
        {
            redirect('/');
        }

        if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in_admin') )
        {
            redirect('admin/login');
        }


    }

...
```

Is this security check of my own IP address 127.0.0.1 - just as an example ;) ) enough?

Can this be broken? If yes how?

Comment: I hid your IP address from the question.

Comment: Thanks, it was just an example not a real IP, but you are right localhost is better.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend it. IP addresses can be shared, reallocated and possibly spoofed.

It is also a system that lacks flexibility. Your Internet connection is down and you need to access the admin area from a mobile connection? Need to grant permission to another user? You have to get access to the source and rewrite the permissions system.

Comment: I will access ftp and change the ip there if it is neccessery. That is not a problem. However, how can somebody from Australia get my IP address in Europe without hacking my provider's servers?